# Set Table cellspacing in JQuery Datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm porting a website from PHP to ASP.NET MVC, and I'm trying to mimic the original JQuery Datepicker.

They used an older version, but I noticed I'll need to change the cellspacing attribute on the generated  of the Datepicker.

Any ideas how this can be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this CSS:

```
<style>

  table.ui-datepicker-calendar{
    border-spacing: 5px;
  }

  .ui-datepicker table{
    border-collapse: inherit;
  }
</style>
```

That border-spacing is the equivalent to cellspacing in CSS. I don't know if you need to adapt other classes in jquery-ui to allow for larger border-spacing values...